# Why is the image stored in the Laravel site with CentOS server but not displayed?

Tags: php, laravel, image, centos, storage

Why is the image stored in the Laravel site with the CentOS server, but it's not displayed and instead this address http://localhost:8000/storage/images/1672938425.jpg is displayed?

I wanted to show the photo

Meanwhile I used this code to configure the image in the share folder in the services folder: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

```php
class ShareService {
    public static function uploadImage($file, $folder) {
        $name = time(). '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('images/' . $folder, $file, $name);
        $path = asset('storage/images/' . $folder . '/' . $name);
        return [$name, $path];
    }
```